# how to sort a vector in c++ according to the ratio of its values

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

I have a vector that its elements consists of two integers. I want to compute the ratio of these 2 integers for every element first, and then sort the vector descending according to this ratio.

Comment: I approve, you may proceed.

Comment: I know there is a "sort" function and takes 3 arguments, I want to know what to put as the third argument ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). That function allows you to sort a collection using a predicate that you may specify yourself. In the example code below I create a `vector` of `pair`s. The `cmp` function compares two of these pairs by calculating the ratio for each and returning `true` if `a`'s ratio is greater than `b`'s.

So effectively you need to specify a function (or a function object, or lambda or whatever) that takes two arguments of your collections element-type and compares them. If `a` should come before `b`, then the function should return `true`, and if not then it should return `false`. That function is the third argument for `std::sort`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

bool cmp(const std::pair<int, int>& a, const std::pair<int, int>& b)
{
    // you should probably also add some code to prevent dividing by zero...
    return (static_cast<double>(a.first)/a.second) > (static_cast<double>(b.first)/b.second);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > pairs;
    std::sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), &cmp);
}
```

Comment: Just be careful with the ratio of two integers. You have to cast them to real before de div !

Comment: @Caduchon Or not. Depends on what you're after. But yes, if you want a non-integer result, you have to cast at least one of them to a floating number.

Comment: Anyway, I changed the post accordingly.

Comment: @Angew: for me, [ (1,3) , (1,5) , (1,2) , (1,17) ] is not a sorted vector...

Comment: "sort the vector *descending* according to this ratio" - you've got ascending in "[a] < [b]".

Comment: Then you just have to call `std::sort(pairs.rbegin(), pairs.rend(), &cmp);`

Comment: @TonyD: has been fixed.

Comment: +1 from me... cheers.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main ( )
{
    typedef std::pair<int, int> elem_t;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs;
    std::sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), [](elem_t const & e1, elem_t const & e2)
    {
        e1.first * e2.second < e1.second * e2.first;
    });
}
```

If you don't know the `[](...){...}` syntax, it is a lambda-expression from c++11.

Note that comparing multiplies the way I done it has a better precision that dividing (because integer division takes place), but can lead to overflow.

Comment: Yes sorry - misread what you'd done, still "e1.first * e2.second < e1.second * e2.first;" - the question asks for *descending* order, so it should be '>' in this comparison, or values reversed.  +1 for lambdas.

Comment: The standard operator is always '<'. If you want to sort with descending order, use rbegin() and rend().

Comment: That'd work too, though arguably it's kind of the point of accepting a comparitor that it can define non-standard ordering, and personally I think people reading the code are more likely to focus on the comparison and might miss the relatively subtle change to `rbegin` and `rend`.  Each to their own!  Cheers.

Comment: @Caduchon Yes, but this one is not using the standard operator, it's using a custom comparator. Sorting with a custom comparator (and a single-purpose one, at that) and using `rbegin()`+`rend()` is just confusing in my book and wouldn't pass code review with me.